# String matching function between two columns using Levenshtein distance in PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, levenshtein-distance

I am trying to compare pairs of names by converting the levenshtein distance between them to a matching coef such as :

coef = 1 - Levenstein(str1, str2) / max(length(str1) , length(str2))

However, when I implement it in PySpark using withColumn(), I get errors whe computing the max() function. Both numpy.max and pyspark.sql.functions.max throw errors. Any idea ?

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, length, levenshtein

valuesA = [('Pirate',1),('Monkey',2),('Ninja',3),('Spaghetti',4)]
TableA = spark.createDataFrame(valuesA,['firstname','id'])

test_compare = TableA.withColumnRenamed('firstname', 'firstname2').withColumnRenamed('id', 'id2').crossJoin(TableA)
test_compare.withColumn("distance_firstname", levenshtein('firstname', 'firstname2') / max(length(col('firstname')), length(col('firstname2'))))
```

Comment: Hi, you should include the error messages. Also I notice you have a function named length; you should include that as well since it is in the max() call. To make python calculate your length; you could use the built in len(), but that may not fit your purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`max` is an aggregate function, to find greatest between two values you want to use `greatest`, also from `pyspark.sql.functions`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, length, greatest
from pyspark.sql.functions import levenshtein  
valuesA = [('Pirate',1),('Monkey',2),('Ninja',3),('Spaghetti',4)]
TableA = spark.createDataFrame(valuesA,['firstname','id'])

test_compare = TableA.withColumnRenamed('firstname', 'firstname2').withColumnRenamed('id', 'id2').crossJoin(TableA)
test_compare.withColumn("distance_firstname", levenshtein('firstname', 'firstname2') / greatest(length(col('firstname')), length(col('firstname2')))).show()
```